# (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root) when deploying Rails app with Rubber to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm following this tutorial from Railscast on how to deploy your rails-app to EC2:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2

I did something and now I keep getting this error whenever I try to deploy:

```
connection failed for: production.foo.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)
```

It's a very obscure error and seems to be specifically mac related. Another user following the tutorial also had that error:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=comments#comment_158643.

And this guy experienced something similar as well:

https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/182.

I've been through every blog post on this issue and nothing has come up. How would you troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**

This is the full stack trace I get when trying to connect through ssh:

```
➜  HN_Notifier_Web git:(master) ✗ ssh -vvvv -i gsg-keypair.pub ubuntu@ec2-54-242-109-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
Warning: Identity file gsg-keypair.pub not accessible: No such file or directory.
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-242-109-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.225.178.242] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ec2-54-242-109-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com" from file "/Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 126/256
debug2: bits set: 499/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 0c:2f:59:00:c6:ee:26:3f:eb:e5:aa:da:e8:33:dd:a9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ec2-54-242-109-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com" from file "/Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "54.225.178.242" from file "/Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-242-109-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f825141d860)
debug2: key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ec2/gsg-keypair (0x7f825141e700)
debug2: key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ec2/gsg-keypair
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/holgersindbaek/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

**UPDATE**

And here's my rubber.yml:

```
# REQUIRED: The name of your application
app_name: your_app_name

# REQUIRED: The system user to run your app servers as
app_user: app

# REQUIRED: Notification emails (e.g. monit) get sent to this address
#
admin_email: "root@#{full_host}"

# OPTIONAL: If not set, you won't be able to access web_tools
# server (graphite, graylog, monit status, haproxy status, etc)
# web_tools_user: admin
# web_tools_password: sekret

# REQUIRED: The timezone the server should be in
timezone: US/Eastern

# REQUIRED: the domain all the instances should be associated with
#
domain: foo.com

# OPTIONAL: See rubber-dns.yml for dns configuration
# This lets rubber update a dynamic dns service with the instance alias
# and ip when they are created.  It also allows setting up arbitrary
# dns records (CNAME, MX, Round Robin DNS, etc)

# OPTIONAL: Additional rubber file to pull config from if it exists.  This file will
# also be pushed to remote host at Rubber.root/config/rubber/rubber-secret.yml
#
# rubber_secret: "#{File.expand_path('~') + '/.ec2' + (Rubber.env == 'production' ? '' : '_dev') + '/rubber-secret.yml' rescue ''}"

# OPTIONAL: Encryption key that was used to obfuscate the contents of rubber-secret.yml with "rubber util:obfuscation" 
# Not that much better when stored in here, but you could use a ruby snippet in here to fetch it from a key server or something
#
# rubber_secret_key: "XXXyyy=="

# REQUIRED All known cloud providers with the settings needed to configure them
# There's only one working cloud provider right now - Amazon Web Services
# To implement another, clone lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb or make the fog provider 
# work in a generic fashion
#
cloud_providers:
  aws:
    # REQUIRED The AWS region that you want to use.
    # 
    # Options include
    # us-east-1
    # eu-west-1
    # ap-northeast-1
    # ap-southeast-1
    # ap-southeast-2
    #
    region: us-east-1

    # REQUIRED The amazon keys and account ID (digits only, no dashes) used to access the AWS API
    #
    access_key: XXX
    secret_access_key: YYY
    account: 'ZZZ'

    # REQUIRED:  The name of the amazon keypair and location of its private key
    #
    # NOTE: for some reason Capistrano requires you to have both the public and
    # the private key in the same folder, the public key should have the
    # extension ".pub".  The easiest way to get your hand on this is to create the
    # public key from the private key: ssh-keygen -y -f gsg-keypair > gsg-keypair.pub
    #
    key_name: gsg-keypair
    key_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/*' + cloud_providers.aws.key_name].first}"

    # OPTIONAL: Needed for bundling a running instance using rubber:bundle
    #
    # pk_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/pk-*'].first}"
    # cert_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/cert-*'].first}"
    # image_bucket: "#{app_name}-images"

    # OPTIONAL: Needed for backing up database to s3
    # backup_bucket: "#{app_name}-backups"

    # REQUIRED: the ami and instance type for creating instances
    # The Ubuntu images at http://alestic.com/ work well
    # Ubuntu 12.04 Precise instance-store 64-bit: ami-eafa5883
    #
    # m1.small or m1.large or m1.xlarge
    image_type: c1.medium
    image_id: ami-b6089bdf

    # OPTIONAL: EC2 spot instance request support.
    #
    # Enables the creation of spot instance requests.  Rubber will wait synchronously until the request is fulfilled,
    # at which point it will begin initializing the instance, unless spot_instance_request_timeout is set.
    # spot_instance: true
    #
    # The maximum price you would like to pay for your spot instance.
    # spot_price: "0.085"
    #
    # If a spot instance request can't be fulfilled in 3 minutes, fallback to on-demand instance creation.  If not set,
    # the default is infinite.
    # spot_instance_request_timeout: 180

  # Use an alternate cloud provider supported by fog.  This doesn't fully work
  # yet due to differences in providers within fog, but gives you a starting
  # point for contributing a new provider to rubber.  See rubber/lib/rubber/cloud(.rb)
  fog:
    credentials:
      provider: rackspace
      rackspace_api_key: 'XXX'
      rackspace_username: 'YYY'
    image_type: 123
    image_id: 123

# REQUIRED the cloud provider to use
#
cloud_provider: aws

# OPTIONAL: Where to store instance data.
# 
# Allowed forms are:
# filesystem: "file:#{Rubber.root}/config/rubber/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"
# cloud storage (s3): "storage:#{cloud_provider.aws.backup_bucket}/RubberInstances_#{app_name}/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"
# cloud table (simpledb): "table:RubberInstances_#{app_name}_#{Rubber.env}"
#
# If you need to port between forms, load the rails console then:
# Rubber.instances.save(location)
# where location is one of the allowed forms for this variable
#
# instance_storage: "file:#{Rubber.root}/config/rubber/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"

# OPTIONAL: Where to store a backup of the instance data
#
# This is most useful when using a remote store in case you end up
# wiping the single copy of your instance data.  When using the file
# store, the instance file is typically under version control with
# your project code, so that provides some safety.
#
# instance_storage_backup: "storage:#{cloud_providers.aws.backup_bucket}/RubberInstances_#{app_name}/instance-#{Rubber.env}-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}.yml"

# OPTIONAL: Default ports for security groups
web_port: 80
web_ssl_port: 443
web_tools_port: 8080
web_tools_ssl_port: 8443

# OPTIONAL: Define security groups
# Each security group is a name associated with a sequence of maps where the
# keys are the parameters to the ec2 AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress API
# source_security_group_name, source_security_group_owner_id
# ip_protocol, from_port, to_port, cidr_ip
# If you want to use a source_group outside of this project, add "external_group: true"
# to prevent group_isolation from mangling its name, e.g.  to give access to graphite
# server to other projects
#
# security_groups:
#   graphite_server:
#     description: The graphite_server security group to allow projects to send graphite data
#     rules:
#       - source_group_name: yourappname_production_collectd
#         source_group_account: 123456
#         external_group: true
#         protocol: tcp
#         from_port: "#{graphite_server_port}"
#         to_port: "#{graphite_server_port}"
#
security_groups:
  default:
    description: The default security group
    rules:
      - source_group_name: default
        source_group_account: "#{cloud_providers.aws.account}"
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: 22
        to_port: 22
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
  web:
    description: "To open up port #{web_port}/#{web_ssl_port} for http server on web role"
    rules:
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_ssl_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_ssl_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
  web_tools:
    description: "To open up port #{web_tools_port}/#{web_tools_ssl_port} for internal/tools http server"
    rules:
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_tools_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_tools_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_tools_ssl_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_tools_ssl_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]

# OPTIONAL: The default security groups to create instances with
assigned_security_groups: [default]
roles:
  web:
    assigned_security_groups: [web]
  web_tools:
    assigned_security_groups: [web_tools]

# OPTIONAL: Automatically create security groups for each host and role
# EC2 doesn't allow one to change what groups an instance belongs to after
# creation, so its good to have some empty ones predefined.
auto_security_groups: true

# OPTIONAL: Automatically isolate security groups for each appname/environment
# by mangling their names to be appname_env_groupname
# This makes it safer to have staging and production coexist on the same EC2
# account, or even multiple apps
isolate_security_groups: true

# OPTIONAL: Prompts one to sync security group rules when the ones in amazon
# differ from those in rubber
prompt_for_security_group_sync: true

# OPTIONAL: The packages to install on all instances
# You can install a specific version of a package by using a sub-array of pkg, version
# For example, packages: [[rake, 0.7.1], irb]
packages: [postfix, build-essential, git-core, ec2-ami-tools, libxslt-dev, ntp]

# OPTIONAL: gem sources to setup for rubygems
# gemsources: ["https://rubygems.org"]

# OPTIONAL: The gems to install on all instances
# You can install a specific version of a gem by using a sub-array of gem, version
# For example, gem: [[rails, 2.2.2], open4, aws-s3]
gems: [open4, aws-s3, bundler, [rubber, "#{Rubber.version}"]]

# OPTIONAL: A string prepended to shell command strings that cause multi
# statement shell commands to fail fast.  You may need to comment this out
# on some platforms, but it works for me on linux/osx with a bash shell
#
stop_on_error_cmd: "function error_exit { exit 99; }; trap error_exit ERR"

# OPTIONAL: The default set of roles to use when creating a staging instance
# with "cap rubber:create_staging".  By default this uses all the known roles,
# excluding slave roles, but this is not always desired for staging, so you can
# specify a different set here
#
# staging_roles: "web,app,db:primary=true"


# OPTIONAL: Lets one assign amazon elastic IPs (static IPs) to your instances
#           You should typically set this on the role/host level rather than
#           globally , unless you really do want all instances to have a
#           static IP
#
# use_static_ip: true

# OPTIONAL: Specifies an instance to be created in the given availability zone
#           Availability zones are sepcified by amazon to be somewhat isolated
#           from each other so that hardware failures in one zone shouldn't
#           affect instances in another.  As such, it is good to specify these
#           for instances that need to be redundant to reduce your chance of
#           downtime. You should typically set this on the role/host level
#           rather than globally.  Use cap rubber:describe_zones to see the list
#           of zones
# availability_zone: us-east-1a

# OPTIONAL: If you want to use Elastic Block Store (EBS) persistent
# volumes, add them to host specific overrides and they will get created
# and assigned to the instance.  On initial creation, the volume will get
# attached _and_ formatted, but if your host disappears and you recreate
# it, the volume will only get remounted thereby preserving your data
#
# hosts:
#   my_host:
#     availability_zone: us-east-1a
#     volumes:
#       - size: 100 # size of vol in GBs
#         zone: us-east-1a # zone to create volume in, needs to match host's zone
#         device: /dev/sdh # OS device to attach volume to
#         mount: /mnt/mysql # The directory to mount this volume to
#         filesystem: ext3 # the filesystem to create on volume
#       - size: 10 # size of vol in GBs
#         zone: us-east-1a # zone to create volume in, needs to match host's zone
#         device: /dev/sdi # OS device to attach volume to
#         mount: /mnt/logs # The directory to mount this volume to
#         filesystem: ext3 # the filesystem to create on volume
#
#       # volumes without mount/filesystem can be used in raid arrays
#
#       - size: 50 # size of vol in GBs
#         zone: us-east-1a # zone to create volume in, needs to match host's zone
#         device: /dev/sdx # OS device to attach volume to
#       - size: 50 # size of vol in GBs
#         zone: us-east-1a # zone to create volume in, needs to match host's zone
#         device: /dev/sdy # OS device to attach volume to
#
#    # Use some ephemeral volumes for raid array
#    local_volumes:
#      - partition_device: /dev/sdb
#        zero: false # zeros out disk for improved performance
#      - partition_device: /dev/sdc
#        zero: false # zeros out disk for improved performance
#
#     # for raid array, you'll need to add mdadm to packages.  Likewise,
#     # xfsprogs is needed for xfs filesystem support
#     #
#     packages: [xfsprogs, mdadm]
#     raid_volumes:
#       - device: /dev/md0 # OS device to to create raid array on
#         mount: /mnt/fast # The directory to mount this array to
#         mount_opts: 'nobootwait' # Recent Ubuntu versions require this flag or SSH will not start on reboot
#         filesystem: xfs # the filesystem to create on array
#         filesystem_opts: -f # the filesystem opts in mkfs
#         raid_level: 0 # the raid level to use for the array
#         # if you're using Ubuntu 11.x or later (Natty, Oneiric, Precise, etc)
#         # you will want to specify the source devices in their /dev/xvd format
#         # see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/684875 for
#         # more information.
#         # NOTE: Only make this change for raid source_devices, NOT generic
#         # volume commands above.
#         source_devices: [/dev/sdx, /dev/sdy] # the source EBS devices we are creating raid array from (Ubuntu Lucid or older)
#         source_devices: [/dev/xvdx, /dev/xvdy] # the source EBS devices we are creating raid array from (Ubuntu Natty or newer)
#
#     # for LVM volumes, you'll need to add lvm2 to packages.  Likewise,
#     # xfsprogs is needed for xfs filesystem support
#     packages: [xfsprogs, lvm2]
#     lvm_volume_groups:
#       - name: vg # The volume group name
#         physical_volumes: [/dev/sdx, /dev/sdy] # Devices used for LVM group (you can use just one, but you can't stripe then)
#         extent_size: 32 # Size of the volume extent in MB
#         volumes:
#           - name: lv # Name of the logical volume
#             size: 999.9 # Size of volume in GB (slightly less than sum of all physical volumes because LVM reserves some space)
#             stripes: 2 # Count of stripes for volume
#             filesystem: xfs # The filesystem to create on the logical volume
#             filesystem_opts: -f # the filesystem opts in mkfs
#             mount: /mnt/large_work_dir # The directory to mount this LVM volume to

# OPTIONAL: You can also define your own variables here for use when
# transforming config files, and they will be available in your config
# templates as  <%%= rubber_env.var_name %>
#
# var_name: var_value

# All variables can also be overridden on the role, environment and/or host level by creating
# a sub level to the config under roles, environments and hosts.  The precedence is host, environment, role
# e.g. to install mysql only on db role, and awstats only on web01:

# OPTIONAL: Role specific overrides
# roles:
#   somerole:
#     packages: []
#   somerole2:
#     myconfig: someval

# OPTIONAL: Environment specific overrides
# environments:
#   staging:
#     myconfig: otherval
#   production:
#     myconfig: val

# OPTIONAL: Host specific overrides
# hosts:
#   somehost:
#     packages: []
```

Comment: I think it might have something to do with my RSA key, since I've been having issues with that as well, but as far as I know, Rubber shouldn't use the RSA key should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I"m not sure what I did wrong and what I did right here. There seems to be a few bugs in rubber.

In the end I made a new app, deployed the way it's done in the second half of the Railscast (with individual instances). After that I logged into AWS, clicked in the instance -> actions -> connect. There you can see the "correct" way to connect to the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Rubber expects to be given your EC2 credentials in the YAML file `config/rubber/rubber.yml`

```
access_key: xxx
secret_access_key: blah
account: 123
```

To find these values:

- Sign into AWS
- In the top right of the screen, click your username and select `Security Credentials`
- The `account` number is near the top right of the page that opens
- Your `access_key` is halfway down this page and there is a link to see your `secret_access_key`

Rubber uses these credentials to configure your AWS infrastructure.

When connecting to an actual server, it will require your secret RSA key.  You need to tell rubber the name of the keypair (as shown in your EC2 dashboard), and its location.  Again in `config/rubber/rubber.yml`

```
key_name: my-keypair
key_file: ~/.ec2/myec2.pem
```

Comment: I've also tried changing the user to ubuntu and then it just gives me exactly the same error, just with ubuntu instead of root. Why does it use the RSA key? How do I configure the RSA key for EC2?

Comment: I've already done this. Tried it several times with new Rails test apps and it won't work. I'm also linking to the right key pair, the right place, so it shouldn't be that,

Comment: Have you told Rubber the location of your keypair?  Can you post your rubber.yml? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ya, I've told rubber about the location of the keypad. It's called gsg-keypair and is located under ~/.ec2/gsg-keypair. It doesn't have a .pem extension though. I have one key without an extension, which I've set the RW-access to 400 and one with a .pub extension.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need the .pem extension.  You seem to be doing everything right.

Comment: Ya... that's what's confusing me immensely! How would you troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: Change the key_file argument in your rubber.yml to the verbatim location of your keyfile, not the verbose logic that is from the Railscast. Also, make sure it points at the private key (no extension) not the public key (.pub)